# Como puedo colocarle una sentencia WHERE a esta consulta?

Tags: mysql, nodejs

Consulta:

```
SELECT `i`.`name`, `i`.`id`, `i`.`img`, `d`.`url`, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name SEPARATOR ', ') as tags
FROM `demos` i 
INNER JOIN `details` d ON `i`.`id` = `d`.`demo_id`
INNER JOIN tags t ON t.demo_id = i.id
GROUP BY `i`.`id`
ORDER BY `i`.`created_at` ASC
```

Una idea de como debería quedar

```
SELECT `i`.`name`, `i`.`id`, `i`.`img`, `d`.`url`, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name SEPARATOR ', ') as tags
FROM `demos` i
INNER JOIN `details` d ON `i`.`id` = `d`.`demo_id`
INNER JOIN tags t ON t.demo_id = i.id
GROUP BY `i`.`id`
WHERE i.id = req.params.id
```

Comment: Y cual es el error? o el problema? a simple vista el where va siempre antes de un group by, pero específica el problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El WHERE debe ir después del FROM y JOINS

```
SELECT `i`.`name`, `i`.`id`, `i`.`img`, `d`.`url`, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name SEPARATOR ', ') as tags
FROM `demos` i
INNER JOIN `details` d ON `i`.`id` = `d`.`demo_id`
INNER JOIN tags t ON t.demo_id = i.id

WHERE i.id = req.params.id

GROUP BY `i`.`id`
```

Comment: Intente lo que sugieres pero tengo el siguiente error Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column '6j5y9v' in 'where clause'

Comment: que es esto <req.params.id>? Prueba con un valor en duro y depura... debes validar inicialmente tu sintax

Comment: Es la id del demo que estoy necesitando

Comment: Esta es la consulta que se esta haciendo SELECT `i`.`name`, `i`.`id`, `i`.`img`, `d`.`url`, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name SEPARATOR ', ') as tags FROM `demos` i INNER JOIN `details` d ON `i`.`id` = `d`.`demo_id`  INNER JOIN tags t ON t.demo_id = i.id WHERE i.id = 6j5y9v GROUP BY `i`.`id`

Comment: y que tipo de dato es <req.params.id> al parecer es cadena, en ese sentido debes colocarlo con apostrofe '6j5y9v'

Answer (score 0):

Buen día el Where va antes del GROUP BY

SELECT `i`.`name`, `i`.`id`, `i`.`img`, `d`.`url`, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name SEPARATOR ', ') as tags
FROM `demos` i
INNER JOIN `details` d ON `i`.`id` = `d`.`demo_id`
INNER JOIN tags t ON t.demo_id = i.id

WHERE i.id = req.params.id

GROUP BY `i`.`id`

Saludos